# Rewriting C# code in ColdFusion while still using .NET objects

Tags: .net, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

I was wondering if anybody could help me rewrite the following C# code in CFML? I have access to DLLs and can successfully access the classes using `CFOBJECT`. What I can't work out is how to translate the following syntax from C# to CFML. I've been trying all afternoon and am getting nowhere and I can't find any good tutorials on doing anything like this.

The API reference can be seen at http://api.korzh.com/easyquery/asp-net.

The code is as follows:

```
using Korzh.EasyQuery;
using Korzh.EasyQuery.Db;
using Korzh.EasyQuery.WebControls;

protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  DbQuery query = (DbQuery)Session["QUERY"];
  if (query == null) {  
      //we didn't open this page before

      string modelPath = this.MapPath("~/App_Data/MyModel.xml");

      Korzh.EasyQuery.DataModel model = new Korzh.EasyQuery.Db.DbModel(); 
      model.LoadFromFile(modelPath); 

      query = new Korzh.EasyQuery.Db.DbQuery(); 
      query.Model = model;

      query.Formats.SetDefaultFormats(FormatType.MsSqlServer); 
      Session["QUERY"] = query;
  }
}
```

Many thanks!

**Clarification:**

EasyQuery provide a set of jQuery widgets which use a JSON representation of your database (I do not have any issue with generating the data model as this can be done using a tool provided by EasyQuery) to show the correct columns etc. in the query builder.

When the query is built in the UI it can be sent to the server. The query isn't sent as SQL which would be a security risk but is sent as some kind of obfuscated string. The ASP.NET classes can then be used to convert this string into SQL so a query can be run against a database. What I want to be able to do is to use these ASP.NET classes in ColdFusion to convert the string into SQL.

I believe (but am not sure) that the code at http://docs.korzh.com/easyquery/aspnet/getting-started-webforms demonstrates how to generate the SQL.

Comment: I you are trying to query a DB, you should look up `<cfquery>` or ColdFusions ORM functions

Comment: I am trying to implement the [EasyQuery](http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/asp-net/) query builder in an application. It has a very nice UI but the back-end is ASP.NET. Therefore I want to access the ASP.NET classes via ColdFusion.

Comment: Is Korzh.EasyQuery not a class you can access with cfobject?

Comment: I am not familiar with it, but .. in theory, you should be able to create the .net objects w/createObject in any .cfm page and use the CF equivalent of `session`. However, being able to use the library also depends on how tightly integrated it is with C# *web* components. AFAIK, you cannot use .net gui components from CF, so if it has those kind of dependencies it may not be compatible. Out of curiosity, do you intend to use this component for developers .. or users?

Comment: *I have access to DLLs and can successfully access the classes using CFOBJECT* Can you post what you have tried so far? Because (assuming the library is compatible w/CF), it should just be a few `createObject` calls (or `cfobject` if you prefer cfml). So I am wondering what issues/errors you have run into.

Comment: The errors I'm running into are all of my own making as I don't really understand the .NET code so am unsure what I am trying to replicate in CF. It seems you may be right though about the classes being incompatible due to their use of web components. Time to look for a better solution. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The Easy Appears to be a complete app that generates SQL queries. It reminds me of a really good looking replacement for Management Studio

[image]

**CFQUERY**

If you are looking to run SQL, you would just copy the SQL in the lower left corner into `<cfquery>` tag. (Recommended)

**CFOBJECT**
If you are looking to tap into a .Net object via ColdFusion, that can be done via

```
<cfobject type=".NET" name="mathInstance" class="mathClass"> 
    assembly="C:/Net/Assemblies/math.dll">
<cfset myVar=mathInstance.multiply(1,2)>
```

**Source:** https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfobject%3A+.NET+object

If you are looking to rebuild this app in ColdFusion, that is a very large project, and beyond the scope of a SO topic

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the XmlParse to read the xml file into a  so it can be processed by Coldfusion. I'm not sure that there is a routine to generate the sql to setup the db model in SQL Server.